# SQL: How to Count occurrences in TableA, join with TableB and then order by occurences?

Tags: php, mysql, join, count, sql-order-by

#### What I want:

For every User that is connected to Group_ID=1 I want to count the amount of activities this User have attended, and use that info to order by User with the most attendings DESC(ending).

*A table that connects Users to Groups:*

```
user_r_group:

ID    User_ID    Group_ID

1     1          1
2     3          1
3     2          1
4     1          2  <-- User 1 connected to another group
```

*A table that shows which activities User have attended:*

```
activities_attended:

ID    Activity_ID    User_ID

1     1              1  <-- User 1 have attended 3 activities
2     1              3
3     1              2
4     2              1  <-- User 1 have attended 3 activities
5     2              3
6     3              1  <-- User 1 have attended 3 activities
```

**The outcome I'm looking for:**

```
User_ID    Attendings

1          3
3          2
2          1
```

## Is there a way to write a mysql_query to achieve this?

It sure feels like it. Or will I need to puzzle myself with loops in php with querycombinations?

I've checked out ways to [join tables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10060325/2808954), and I'm slightly familiar with [ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2283305/2808954), but I have no real clue how to store the attendings-info for every User and then order by it, to then put it all together in a query as wanted ;/ A lil help please?

---

*Solved it!*

Thanks to [GordonM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477127/gordonm) for guidance on where to look, and thanks to [Milen Pavlov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1793906/milen-pavlov) as well as [Kirill Fuchs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1445460/kirill-fuchs) for the code-samples. I combined the codes into my own prefered version. Kirill's code was however accurate on exception that he forgot the 'ORDER BY Attendings DESC' in the end ;)

```
SELECT
    COUNT(aa.User_ID) as Attendings,
    urg.User_ID
FROM
    activities_attended aa
    INNER JOIN user_r_group urg ON urg.User_ID=aa.User_ID
WHERE
    urg.Group_ID=1
GROUP BY
    urg.User_ID
ORDER BY
    Attendings DESC
```

Comment: Yes, there is.  It involves a join and an aggregate function, hopefully that's more than enough info for you to find what you're looking for

Comment: And don't use `mysql_*` functions as they're error-prone and deprecated. Either use `mysqli_*` or even better: [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: @GordonM, found it! Thx. Combined some answers here to get what I wanted(Kirills at ~95% accuracy code-wise), will post my own answer to it with exact working result as well as recognition to involved parts. (Just waiting for 10+ rep or 8hours-limit for new users -.-)

Comment: @nietonfir, you are right, and I'm currently in the process of converting to PDO. Though, since I just started to code I wanted to get a glimpse of the standard issue to gain some perspective on the differences :)

Comment: @TimLind Glad you had some success. It's always better if you can work things out for yourself as they're more likely to stay with you in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use a join. Example below:

```
SELECT `user_r_group`.`User_ID`, count(`activities_attended`.`ID`) AS Attendings
            FROM `user_r_group`
            INNER JOIN `activities_attended`
                    ON `user_r_group`.`User_ID` = `activities_attended`.`User_ID`
            WHERE `user_r_group`.`Group_ID` = 1
                    GROUP BY `user_r_group`.`User_ID`
                    ORDER BY Attendings DESC
```